# Mots composés avec un verbe, un trait d'union et un nom

Tags: traduction, mots-composés

En voici des exemples: tire-bouchon, ouvre-bouteille, lave-vaisselle,
essuie-glace, sèche-linge, coupe-papier.

Ce type de construction m'intéresse pour deux raisons:  la traduction anglaise est toujours dans l'ordre inverse (le nom suivi du verbe):

corkscrew, bottle opener, dish washer, windshield wiper, clothes dryer, paper cutter; le nom ainsi composé semble toujours être masculin.

Existe-t-il un terme pour ce type de construction?  Quelqu'un pourrait-il en donner d'autres exemples?

Comment: On remarque aussi qu'en anglais (d'après tes exemples en tout cas, je ne sais pas si c'est systématique), le verbe est substantivé.

Answer (score 4):

Le terme consacré est composés VN (Verbe-Nom). Vous trouverez une somme d'informations sur leur analyse ainsi qu'une très grande liste de composés VN dans la [thèse de F. Villoing](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01363526/document).

Answer (score 2):

En voici plus. Mais ils n'y a pas de termes que je connais.

> Bouche-trou
>   Pousse-café
>   Tourne-disque
>   Tourne-vent
>   Ouvre-boîte

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Le vrai terme pour parler de ce genre de mots est **"composé lexical à trait d'union"**. Mais celui-ci ne désigne pas forcément un nom suivi d'un verbe. Il peut aussi désigner un nom suivi d'un autre nom... Si vous voulez en savoir plus, je vous invite à vous rendre sur [ce lien.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_compos%C3%A9#Compos.C3.A9s_lexicaux_.C3.A0_traits_d.27union)

Voici quelques exemples :

> Arc-en-ciel
>
> Après-midi
>
> Remonte-pente
>
> Arrière-boutique ...

Si vous voulez plus d'exemples je peux vous en donner.

Source : [Wikipedia Fr](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_compos%C3%A9#Compos.C3.A9s_lexicaux_.C3.A0_traits_d.27union)

Comment: Ces composés ne correspondent pas à la description donnée dans la question...

Comment: Je n'avais trouvé que ce terme pour désigner nom+verbe